# Increment the section number with 1, not 0.1

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Section numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/section-numbering)

I'm happy with the logical layout of my document, but the section numbering is bugging me.

I'd like the first section (the introduction) to be 1, not 1.1. Also, the second section should be 2, not 1.2 (yes, that's a one, like it is still the introduction). I'm getting something wrong, obviously. (I also want sections beginning at the top of a new page, and page numbering should start with the introduction, if you wonder about the other stuff I had to put in the document header. But those things work.)

Any other suggestions are welcome, of course.

```
% x.tex

\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, draft, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex, final]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./pics/}}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
% some stuff here
\end{titlepage}

\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}

% first section - should have number 1, but have 1.1

\subsection{Services}

% subsection - should be 1.1, is 1.1.1

\section{The algorithm}

% new section - number is 1.2, should be 2

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

With the `article` solution, it suddenly looks like this here and there. Otherwise, it works.

[image: white]

Comment: Your used document class `report` starts sectioning (is this right in English?) with `\chapter`. Thats the reason where your `0.` comes from. Change `\section` to `\chapter` or use document class `article` ...

Comment: @Emanu: I saw it. The problem is that LaTeX stretches the white space between headings and paragraphs. It often ocurs with less text. I think you should try `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg The (original) question about the numbering is a duplicate; the problem with the spacing is better solved by not using the `[H]` option for `figure` or `table` environments. Also trying to place big objects in a page can cause it, but it's a different problem and shows with all standard classes when given the `twoside` option. Please, split the question to another one.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your used document class `report` starts sectioning with `\chapter`. Thats the reason where your `0.` comes from. Change `\section` to `\chapter` or use document class `article`.

The big chunks of white space, especially in the table of contents of your changed MWE (to class `article`), you can solve with macro `\raggedbottom` in your preamble. The problem is that LaTeX stretches the white space between headings and paragraphs. It often ocurs with less text. With `\raggedbottom` LaTeX has not to place the last line of the page always on the same place.

Answer (score 33):

The class `report` uses chapters as its top level sectioning.
(<sub><sup>part ></sup></sub> chapter > section > subsection > …)

If you only want to use sections as the top level you should use the class `article`.
(<sub><sup>part ></sup></sub> section > subsection > …)

In your example, you could add

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

to your preamble so that `\section{}` omits the `1.` but this still produces typographically errors in the Table of Contents. It would be better to just use the class `article`.

Comment: So you would recommend changing to `article` as this is more the intended way? `article` works for the problem described (the numbering), but it looks like there was a side effect. Check out my comment to Kurt above.

Comment: Use `\clearpage` or `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak`. The latter tries to fill the vertical space on the page. (Or loose it completely because you have `\cleardoublepage` there anyway.)

Comment: That didn't help. Take a look at the screenshot I just posted. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to keep the `report` document class and want the sections within each chapter to be numbered `1`, `2`, `3`, etc rather than (if within Chapter 2, say) as `2.1`, `2.2`, `2.3`, etc., you need to redefine the macro `\thesection`. For instance, you could issue the command

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

in the preamble.

Note that this will work even if you don't issue any `\chapter` commands at all.

Comment: Works, but has the whitespace problem described in the comments to the other answers. Have a look at the screenshot I just posted in the question. This is getting all confusing, why did it work before I started to fiddle with this numbering thing?!

Comment: @EmanuelBerg: Are you using `\flushbottom` anywhere in your document? If so, remove it. Also get rid of `\pagebreak`.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg - there is absolutely no connection between redefining the appearance of section-level numbers and the appearance of excess amounts of whitespace. For the latter issue, try implementing some of the other comments, especially the suggestion to insert the instruction `\raggedbottom`, in your document's preamble. I'm not familiar with `\pagebreak`; if it's necessary to create a page break, issue either `\clearpage` or `\newpage`.

Comment: @Mico: Right, check out Kurt's answer, the one I accepted, that solved all my problems with this.

Comment: Sir, I want Section 1 and Section 2 instead of Section 1.1 and 1.2 in report. I can't use artcle because I want \chapter{} also. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman - I suggest you execute the instructions `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}` in the preamble.