# Numbering section: “1” instead of “0.1”

Tags: sectioning, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Section numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/section-numbering)

I have a problem with my numbering in LaTeX. When I do

```
\section{foo}
```

the result is

```
0.1 foo
```

and what I need is

```
1 foo
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [SO]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful here: in particular, which document class are you using?

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [Section numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43024/16595). You most likely use a `\documentclass` that uses an additional level of `\chapter` (above `\section`).