# How come the numbering of my section titles is coming as 0.1.x and not 1.x etc

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am using a thesis package given by my university. Surprisingly the section numbers of thesis are coming as 0.1, 0.1.1  and not 1, 1.1 etc. Please see this [pdf](http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201302/283579/temp.html) and this main [tex file](http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201302/283580/temp.html)

I will be thankful for your suggestion.

Comment: probably your thesis class is based on `book` so has `\section`  numbered within `\chapter` but you have no chapters.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/section-numbering

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think so. See http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201302/283581/thesis.html which shows the template which I downloaded. In that, everything is fine.

Comment: I can't see any information in that link. what happens if you put `\chapter{test}` before your first section?

Comment: One difference b/w the original template and my file is that they use pdflatex and I use only latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as many commenters told you, your style assumes you have chapters, while you do not.

Just put in the preamble of your document the line

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

It will tell LaTeX you want sections to be numbered as 1, 2, 3, rather than CHAPTER.SECTION as your style wants.

Comment: That's a workaround for normal `\section`s; however, the ToC and the bibliography will still show up as (unnumbered) *chapters*. A better way seems to be to use `\chapter` as the main sectioning unit, as intended by the template.

Comment: Strictly saying, you are right.  However, people should be able to (ab)use their templates if this is their wish.

Comment: it's commonly the case that thesis templates are *compulsory* -- if you submit a thesis, it has to conform with the template (otherwise it will be rejected).  so, abuse the template as much as you like, but don't try writing your thesis/dissertation that way.